# Retry after delay on back pressure with Spring Project Reactor?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, project-reactor, backpressure

**Background**

I'm trying to implement something similar to a simple non-blocking rate-limiter with [Spring Project Reactor](https://projectreactor.io/) version 3.3.0. For example, to limit the number to 100 requests per second I use this implementation:

```java
myFlux
      .bufferTimeout(100, Duration.ofSeconds(1))
      .delayElements(Duration.ofSeconds(1))
      ..
```

This works fine for my use case but if the subscriber doesn't keep up with the rate of the `myFlux` publisher it'll (rightly) throw an `OverflowException`:

```java
reactor.core.Exceptions$OverflowException: Could not emit buffer due to lack of requests
    at reactor.core.Exceptions.failWithOverflow(Exceptions.java:215)
    Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 
Assembly trace from producer [reactor.core.publisher.FluxLift] :
    reactor.core.publisher.Flux.bufferTimeout(Flux.java:2780)
```

In my case it's important that all elements are consumed by the subscriber so e.g. dropping on back pressure (`onBackpressureDrop()`) is not acceptable.

**Question**

Is there a way to, instead of dropping elements on back pressure, just pause the publishing of messages until the subscriber has caught up? In my case `myFlux` is publishing a finite, but large set of, elements persisted in a durable database so dropping elements should not be required imho.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`bufferTimeout(int maxSize, Duration maxTime)`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#bufferTimeout-int-java.time.Duration-) requests an unbounded amount of messages, thus being insensitive to backpressure. That makes it unsuitable for your case.

On a conceptual level, `bufferTimeout` cannot be backpressure sensitive, because you clearly instruct the publisher to emit one batch (even if it is empty) for every elapsed duration. If the subscriber is too slow, this will - rightfully - cause an overflow.

Instead, try:

```
myFlux
   .delayElements(Duration.ofMillis(10))
   .buffer(100)
```

or

```
myFlux
   .buffer(100)
   .delayElements(Duration.ofSeconds(1))
```

[`buffer(int maxSize)`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#buffer-int-) requests the correct amount upstream (`request * maxSize`), and so is sensitive to backpressure from the subscribers.

Comment: The docs of `bufferTimeout` seem to be open to multiple interpretations.  A tool like buffer things upto a maximum size or until a timeout hits is normally used to group items into batches (for speed) but to stay responsive when supply is low (timeout).  What's the point of pushing through empty buffers...

Comment: @john16384 Turns out you're right. `bufferTimeout` does NOT emit empty batches.